# Expected value of the second digit of a binary number

Tags: probability

Let's choose a real number ($n$) uniformly between $0$ and $1$ and convert it to binary. Then find the probability of that the second digit equals to $1$. I thought it is $0.5$, because that happens when $n>0.75$ or $0.5>n>0.25$. I simulated this problem with some script to check this solution and I found that it's more likely to have $1$ at the second digit then $0$. I am wondering where is the mistake here. Is it really more likely?

Edit

the code I wrote in python:

```
 Sum=0 

 for i in range(1000):

    n=float_bin(np.random.uniform(0,1),100) 

    Sum+=(float(str(n)[2]))
```

the function float_bin converts float number to binary, i checked it, works fine. I got the Sum variable around 580 and 600.

Comment: As you said it is exactly as likely as having $0$ by symmetry.

Comment: could you be more precise?  Can you show your code, and the results you got?

Comment: I added my code to the question.

Comment: Is `float_bin` a built-in function? What is more likely is the code not doing what you expect

Comment: @Henry float_bin might be here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-floating-to-binary/

Comment: yes i got that function from there

Comment: That is a very convoluted way of getting the second binary digit of a number! (OK, not for Python programmers, but still.) So you need to check it: verify at every step that your expression `float(str(n)[2])` is equal to `1` if and only if `x >= 0.75 or (x >= 0.25 and x < 0.5)`, where `x` is your `np.random.uniform(0,1)`. What do you see?

Comment: Check more carefully in the future. The float_bin function from that web page is garbage: float_bin(0.56) returns .100 correctly, but float_bin(0.52) returns .101, float_bin(0.54) returns .111, float_bin(0.05) returns .100, float_bin(0.09) returns .111, float_bin(0.1) returns .200, float_bin(0.01) returns .200, and float_bin(0.55) returns .120.

Comment: Actually I was too kind. The function as written throws ValueError on input 0.05, 0.1, 0.01, or 0.55, because `(decimal_converter(dec)) * 2` evaluates to an integer at least once and when converted to a string there is no decimal point to split it into two parts. The obvious patch is to set `dec` to 0 in that case, but a better approach is to throw the whole thing away and start over. (0.52, 0.54, and 0.9 give nonsense results instead of an exception even in the original version of the code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the probability should be $\frac12$. To test empirically I used the code

```
import numpy as np
sum=0
N = 1000000
for i in range(N):
    x = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    sum+=(int(x*4)%2)
print(sum/N)
```

I got $0.499982$.

The reason my code works to get that digit is multiplying by $4$ shifts the binary representation up by $2$ digits, then rounding down to an `int` and taking the result mod $2$ gives you the digit in the $1$'s place. I'm guessing your code is not getting the digit correctly in every case. You should also try using a number larger than $1000$ for the number of terms to sum.

Comment: I think the OP means the second digit after the binary point., The digit before the binary point is known to be $0$.

Comment: From "$n>0.75$ or $0.5>n>0.25$" I think you can assume the second digit after the binary point